# how to set minimum amount of input field based on membership dropdown value

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

```
<Form.Label htmlFor="amount">
                Amount
                <span className="text-danger">*</span>
              </Form.Label>
              <Form.Control
                  type="text"
                  name="amount"
                  placeholder="Enter amount"
                  id="amount"
                  className="rounded-0"
                  defaultValue={trusteeFormik.values.amount}
                  onChange={trusteeFormik.handleChange}
                  isInvalid={
                      trusteeFormik.touched.amount && trusteeFormik.errors.amount
                  }
              />
              <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {trusteeFormik.errors.amount}
              </Form.Control.Feedback>
```

---

```
  type_of_membership:yup.string().required("Select Membership"),
    amount: yup.number()
        .min(1) // Set default minimum amount
        .when('type_of_membership', {
            is: (type_of_membership) => type_of_membership === 'trustee',
            then: yup.number().min(5000, 'Minimum amount is 5000'), 
            otherwise: yup.number().min(100000, 'Minimum amount is 100'), 
        }),
```

how to set minimum value if user select trustee dropdpwn values from membership dropdwn then minimum amount should we 5000

**When Dropdown Vlaue Selected **

1. Trustee : Minimum Amount should be 5000 INR
2. Volunteers: Minimum Amount Should be 1 INR
3. Crsfund : Minimum Amount should be 100000 INR